# Belongs or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

I have some collection $t_i , t_j, t_k$ .
Is this conclusion true?

$  \nexists x : x\in ( (t_i \cup t_j) -( t_i  \cap t_j)) $  and

$  \nexists x : x\in ( (t_i \cup t_k) -( t_i  \cap t_k)) $

Then   $  \nexists x : x\in ( (t_j \cup t_k) -( t_j \cap t_k)) $

I try to find counter example , but I  didn't find anything , I  think it's always true  ,i can't proof it . is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first condition is equivalent to $(A\cup B) - (A\cap B) = \emptyset$.

Since $A\cup B\supset A \supset A\cap B$, you get
$$ A\cup B = A = A\cap B$$
and in the same way you get $ B = A\cap B$, hence
$$ A = A\cap B = B$$
The same reasoning applies to the second condition, which yields
$$ A = A\cap C = C$$
You conclude that $A=B=C$ which is equivalent to the thesis.

Comment: @jack M hi thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 2):

The condition $(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=\emptyset$ is equivalent to $A=B$, which I'll let you try and prove for yourself. Thus you're asking if $t_i=t_j$ and $t_i=t_k$ implies that $t_j=t_k$, which is of course true.